# gestion de datos pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo un Dataframe con ciudades

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

csv =StringIO(u'''\
city
bogota
manzanares
guapi
el paso
momil
valencia
beltran
Lima
''')
```

y quiero que busque de una lista el departamento que corresponde a esa ciudad y lo agrege en una columna al lado y finalmente en otra columna coloque el pais.

el resultado debe ser:

> > ```
> >           city          Departamento      Pais
> >      0    bogota           D.C.          COLOMBIA
> >      1    manzanares       Caldas        COLOMBIA
> >      2    lima             Lima          Peru
> > ```

El listado a consultar es asi:

```
csv =parsing_data(u'''\
Pais,Departamento,Ciudad            
COLOMBIA,ANTIOQUIA,MEDELLIN
COLOMBIA,ANTIOQUIA,ABEJORRAL
COLOMBIA,ANTIOQUIA,ABRIAQUI
COLOMBIA,ANTIOQUIA,ALEJANDRIA
COLOMBIA,ANTIOQUIA,AMAGA
COLOMBIA,ANTIOQUIA,AMALFI
COLOMBIA,ANTIOQUIA,ANDES
COLOMBIA,ANTIOQUIA,ANGELOPOLIS
COLOMBIA,ANTIOQUIA,ANGOSTURA
PERU,Lima,Lima
''')
```

**alguna idea??** Gracias!

Comment: ¿Tienes en algún otro archivo la información de a qué departamento y país pertenece cada ciudad?

Comment: si, esa info esta en otro .csv

Comment: Pues edita la pregunta para añadir un ejemplo de la estructura del otro .csv, por favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes leer ambos `csv`, cada uno en un dataframe, usar en ambos dataframes la ciudad como índice y después hacer un `join` del primero con el segundo.

En el siguiente ejemplo el resultado no es muy espectacular, porque en el fragmento del segundo .csv la única ciudad del primer csv que aparece es "Lima". Las que no encuentra las rellena con `NaN`. En tu caso entiendo que tendrás datos más completos.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
csv1 =StringIO(u'''\
city
bogota
manzanares
guapi
el paso
momil
valencia
beltran
Lima
'''.upper())

csv2 =StringIO(u'''\
Pais,Departamento,Ciudad
COLOMBIA,ANTIOQUIA,MEDELLIN
COLOMBIA,ANTIOQUIA,ABEJORRAL
COLOMBIA,ANTIOQUIA,ABRIAQUI
COLOMBIA,ANTIOQUIA,ALEJANDRIA
COLOMBIA,ANTIOQUIA,AMAGA
COLOMBIA,ANTIOQUIA,AMALFI
COLOMBIA,ANTIOQUIA,ANDES
COLOMBIA,ANTIOQUIA,ANGELOPOLIS
COLOMBIA,ANTIOQUIA,ANGOSTURA
PERU,LIMA,LIMA
''')

df1 = pd.read_csv(csv1).set_index("CITY")
df2 = pd.read_csv(csv2).set_index("Ciudad")
resultado = df1.join(df2).reset_index()
```

He tenido que pasar a mayúsculas los nombres de las ciudades en el primer csv para que coincidan con los del segundo. El resultado es:

```
         CITY  Pais Departamento
0      BOGOTA   NaN          NaN
1  MANZANARES   NaN          NaN
2       GUAPI   NaN          NaN
3     EL PASO   NaN          NaN
4       MOMIL   NaN          NaN
5    VALENCIA   NaN          NaN
6     BELTRAN   NaN          NaN
7        LIMA  PERU         LIMA
```